# Nonconstant points of an absolute continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in the nonconstant points of continuous functions. Assume that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then its nonconstant point means the set

$$K=\{x_{0}\in[0,1]:f(x)\neq\text{const}\ in\ any\ neighborhood\ of\ x_{0}\}.$$

This is a closed subset of $[0,1]$, since its complement consists of at most countable intervals. K contains two kinds of points, either intervals or the accumulation points.

If $f(x)$ is an absolute continuous function, could the second case happen? Examples?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the sentence "$K$ contains two kinds of points, either intervals or the accumulation points." Could you clarify?

Comment: Hello, $K=[0,1]\backslash\cup I_{j}$ where $I_{j}$ are disjoint open intervals. Then $K$ must be a union of intervals or accumulation points of end points of $I_{j}$. I think this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{q_n\}$ is an ordering of the rationals in $[0,1]$ and $U_1=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{1/2^{n+2}}(q_n)$ and $U_2=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{1/2^{n+3}}(q_n)$, where $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ denotes the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$, then $U_2\subsetneq U_1$ and $U_1\neq [0,1]$ by considering the sum of the lengths of the intervals, and further, $U_1,U_2$ are open sets containing every rational in $[0,1]$. Let $f_i:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the function $f_i(x)=d(x,U_i^c)$ for $i=1,2$, which is well-defined since $U_i^c$ is closed, and further it is absolutely continuous (in fact, Lipschitz continuous). Therefore, the function $f(x)=f_1(x)-f_2(x)$ is absolutely continuous too.

By definition of $U_i$, we get $K\subset U_2^c$ and $K$ is nonempty (it will contain any element of $U_2\setminus U_1$). But $K^c\supset U_2$ contains every rational in $[0,1]$, which means that every point of $K$ is an accumulation point of $K^c$.

Another example would be the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), for which $K$ would be the Cantor set.